# How to move wpf button blue border like in winform

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

When I start the program in winform, I just need to press key right to be able to move back and forth between the buttons but in wpf I can't.
[image]
I found that when I start the program in winform the first button of winform will have a blue border around it so when I press key right that blue border will go to the next button. In wpf it is not possible to do so
[image]
I don't have any ideas so I hope someone can help. I sincerely thank

Comment: [Focus Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/focus-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Use focus overview like @Clemens said. Also you can set your tabs to in settings to include and/or omit what buttons are included in the tab event.

Answer (score 2):

Use Tabindex to accomplish this

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel>

            <Button TabIndex="0" Content="Button 1" x:Name="Button1" />

            <Button TabIndex="1" Content="Button 2" x:Name="Button2" />

            <Button TabIndex="2" Content="Button 3" x:Name="Button3" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBox1" TabIndex="4" IsReadOnly="True" IsTabStop="False" Background="Gainsboro" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

In your window load, set your first button to focus

```
button1.Focus();
```

Tab index can be applied to any control, if you would ur keystroke to not move to it set  `IsTabStop="False"`